# Recursion using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I am trying to write a function that takes a flat data format which uses a **id** and a **parentId** to establish relationships.  I know I need to use recursion but I need help understanding how to get it in a specific JSON model.

*Here is the flat source data, the id's are guids as you can see.*

```
     {"id":"e6168d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","parentId":"","label":"OGC File List"}

     {"id":"17168d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","parentId":"e6168d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","label":"Accounting"}

     {"id":"h37s8d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","parentId":"17168d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","label":"Policy"}

     {"id":"f8ke6d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","parentId":"17168d55-1974-e411-80e0-005056971214","label":"Policy"}
```

Below is the model I need to create.  I only need help with the properties id: inode: which indicates the node has children and the branch which is  the array of child objects.  Building the branches is what confounds me the most.  I appreciate any assistance or direction in advance!

```
[
        {
            id: 'folder_1',
            label: 'This is Folder 1',
            inode: true,
            open: false,
            icon: 'folder'
            branch:
                [
                    {
                        id: 'sub-item_x',
                        label: 'This is File X',
                        inode: false,
                        icon: 'file'
                    },
                    ...
                ]
        },
        {
            id: 'file_1',
            label: 'This is File 1',
            inode: false,
            icon: 'file'
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
var list = [{...},{...},...{...}]; //folder list in JSON format == JS object
var tree = buildChildrenList('');  //find root folders first

function buildChildrenList(parentId){
    var childrens = [];
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        if (list[i].parentId == parentId){
            childrens.push({
                 id: list[i].id,
                 label: list[i].label,
                 inode: true,
                 open: false,
                 icon: 'folder',
                 branch: buildChildrenList(list[i].id) //this is a recursive call
            });
        }
    }
    return childrens;
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to test now.  branch: is getting a error "missing }".  I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you Ragnar, I wish I could up-vote this 10 times, very clean and way more simple than my approach.